# How to execute the same query for several dynamically decided dates in a single DAG run?

Tags: airflow

The main idea is to run `BigQueryOperator` for several specific dynamically determined dates (so the date must be passed to an external query) and that the results are written to corresponding partitions (using the `$` suffix of the destination table) all in a single DAG run. Dates are dependent on the `execution_date`.

I understand that `user_defined_macros` only exist on (sub)DAG level, so I will have to spawn subDAGs dynamically. But `execution_date` is only available within operators, such as `PythonOperator`, and it does not seem possible to spawn a subDAG (or any operator for that matter) from inside another operator.

So either I need a way to access `execution_date` not from an operator but from within a DAG itself, or an alternative way of passing my custom date to the external query without `user_defined_macros` on (sub)DAG level.

Is there a standard way (or any way) of dealing with similar situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently it is possible to pass Jinja-readable parameters to the `BigQueryOperator` to be used both in the query and in partition suffix, like so -

```py
def bq_to_bq_fn(day_offset=None):
    return BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_to_bq' if day_offset is None else f'bq_to_bq_{day_offset}',
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        write_disposition=write_mode_dag,
        allow_large_results=True,
        params={
            'day_offset': 0 if day_offset is None else day_offset
        },
        sql='''
            SELECT * FROM TEST.test1
            WHERE date = '{{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=params.day_offset)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}'
         ''',
        time_partitioning={"type": "DAY", "field": "date"},
        destination_dataset_table=project_id + '.TEST.test2$' + '{{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=params.day_offset)).strftime("%Y%m%d") }}',
        dag=dag
    )
```

The SQL part can also be in an external file.